# external IP not being generated for elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I followed the commands mentioned on this page...

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/index.html

elastic service is stared successfully. But I do not see external-ip

```
#  /usr/local/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig="wzone2.yaml" get service
NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes                ClusterIP   10.245.0.1      <none>        443/TCP    10m
quickstart-es             ClusterIP   10.245.97.209   <none>        9200/TCP   3m11s
quickstart-es-discovery   ClusterIP   None            <none>        9300/TCP   3m11s
```

I tried port forwarding command but that did not help.

> kubectl port-forward service/quickstart-es 9200

How do I connect to this elastic server?

Answer (score 1):

ClusterIP services are only available from inside the cluster. To make it visible from the outside you would need to change it to LoadBalancer type, and have an implementation of that available (read: be running on a cloud provider or use MetalLB).

Comment: I am using digital ocean and it supports LoadBalancer type. But I am not sure how to use it with elastic.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of using a LoadBalancer like @coderanger suggested, you can also use a service of type [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).  This will allow you to connect to your service using the node IP address and without depending on cloud providers.